# Unresolved Error when building Boost.Python

Tags: boost-python

I am trying to run an [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/python/doc/building.html#basic-procedure) during installation of Boost.Python on my Windows7 64-bit machine.

My boost is installed at `C:\local\boost_1_54_0`. Thus at step 3.1.4, I entered

> b2 toolset=msvc --build-type=complete --verbose-test test

However, in the command prompt window, I've got 135 unresolved external errors. These errors all point to a serie of files that has the same prefix `boost_python-vc110-gd-1_54`, the extentions are such as `.rsp`, `.dll` etc., and they should be at `C:\local\boost_1_54_0\bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-11\debug\`.

May I know what am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**This worked for me to build Boost.Python "example"**

1.) Unzip boost_1_55_0.zip

2.) Prepare to use the Boost Library Binaries

Go to the boost_1_55_0 root directory  and open a command prompt and type following commands:

```
Bootstrap
```

3.) Find user-config.jam:

Type following in the command prompt:

```
ECHO %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%
```

4.) If the user-config.jam is in your homedrive directory please change it there as followed:

ATTENTION:

The .jam language rates a “whitespace” as a separation of arguments!

```
# -------------------
# MSVC configuration.
# -------------------

# Configure msvc (default version, searched for in standard locations and PATH).
# using msvc ;

# Configure specific msvc version (searched for in standard locations and PATH).
using msvc : 10.0 : C:\\app\\tools\\MSVisualStudio2010\\VC\\bin\\cl.exe ;

….

# ---------------------
# Python configuration.
# ---------------------

# Configure specific Python version.
# using python : 3.1 : /usr/bin/python3 : /usr/include/python3.1 : /usr/lib ;

using python 
    : 2.5                   # Version
    : C:\\app\\tools\\Python25\\python.exe      # Python Path
    : C:\\app\\tools\\Python25\\include         # include path
    : C:\\app\\tools\\Python25\\libs            # lib path(s)
    : <define>BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1
    ;
```

5.) Build the Libraries AFTER configuration!!

Go to the boost_1_55_0 root directory  and open a command prompt and type following commands:

```
.\b2
```

6.) Copy the user-config.jam to \boost_1_55_0\libs\python\example\tutorial

7.) Go further to \boost_1_55_0\stage\lib\

Rename libboost_python-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.lib to boost_python-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.lib and copy it to

```
\boost_1_55_0\libs\python\example\tutorial
```

8.) Now you should have all of these files in the \boost_1_55_0\libs\python\example\tutorial directory

```
hello.cpp
hello.py
user-config.jam
Jamroot
boost_python-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.lib
bjam.exe
```

9.) Open a command prompt in \boost_1_55_0\libs\python\example\tutorial

And type following command:

```
bjam
```

10.) After successful building..

You should have this file in the directory:

```
hello_ext.dll
```

rename this file to:

```
hello_ext.pyd
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want --build-type=complete, it won't know which one to run. Also, I believe that only the threading=multi, link=shared will work.

I've [documented what I had to do](https://gist.github.com/teeks99/bb4921dffc8a74423c26#file-boost-python-quickstart-md) to get this working myself.