# Cannot successfully install Boost.Python

Tags: c++, boost-python

I am trying to install Boost.Python on my computer. (Windows7 64bit, Visual Studio 2012, Python 2.7 64bit and Boost 1.54)

Following the instruction, I've successfully installed the Boost Library, and then I have to separately install Boost.Python.

However, as I followed the instruction at [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/python/doc/building.html#basic-procedure). I am stuck at step 3.1.4.

I input `C:\boost_1_54_0\…\quickstart> bjam toolset=msvc --verbose-test test`

Then there are 135 unresolved external errors pop out. One of them is:

> exec.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   __imp__PyEval_GetGlobals referenced in function "class boost::python::api::object __cdecl boost::python::eval(class
>   boost::python::str,class boost::python::api::object,class
>   boost::python::api::object)"
>   (?eval@python@boost@@YA?AVobject@api@12@Vstr@12@V3412@1@Z)........\bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-11.0\debug\boost_python-vc110-gd-1_54.dll

May I know how can I work around this?

=========================================================

Edit:

Following @Kyle 's advice, I've uninstalled the 64bit Python and replace it with a 32bit Python (2.7.5).

Then I've wrote a very simple code, which is like follows:

```
#include <boost\python.hpp>       // This header used to raise error before
#include <Python.h>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    return;
}
```

It works well. Then my curiosity pushed me one step further, and I tried the example in my first post. It turns out that those 135 unresolved external errors are gone. Instead, I've got this:

> msvc.link.dll bin\msvc-11.0\debug\extending.pyd LINK : fatal error
>
> LNK1104: cannot open file 'boost_python-vc110-mt-gd-1_54.lib'
>
> call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
>
> nullink /NOLOGO /INCREMENTAL:NO /DLL /DEBUG /MACHINE:X86 /MANIFEST /subsystem:console 
>   /out:"bin\msvc-11.0\debug\extending.pyd"
>   /IMPLIB:"bin\msvc-11.0\debug\extendi ng.lib"
>   /LIBPATH:"C:\Python2.7.5\libs"
>   @"bin\msvc-11.0\debug\extending.pyd.rsp "
>
> ```
>     if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 EXIT %ERRORLEVEL%
> ```
>
> ...failed msvc.link.dll bin\msvc-11.0\debug\extending.pyd
>
> bin\msvc-11.0\debug\extending.lib bin\msvc-11.0\debug\extending.pdb...
>
> ...skipped test_ext for lack of extending.pyd...
>
> msvc.link bin\test_embed.test\msvc-11.0\debug\test_embed.exe LINK : warning
>
> LNK4001: no object files specified; libraries used LINK : error
>
> LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mainCRTStartup
>
> bin\test_embed.test\msvc-11.0\debug\test_embed.exe : fatal error
>
> LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
>
> call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86 nul
>
> link /NOLOGO /INCREMENTAL:NO /DEBUG /MACHINE:X86 /MANIFEST /subsystem:console
>
> /out:"bin\test_embed.test\msvc-11.0\debug\test_embed.exe"
>
> /LIBPATH:"C:\Python2.7.5\libs"
>
> @"bin\test_embed.test\msvc-11.0\debug\test_embed.exe.rsp"
>
> ```
>     if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 EXIT %ERRORLEVEL%
> ```
>
> ...failed msvc.link bin\test_embed.test\msvc-11.0\debug\test_embed.exe
>
> bin\test_ embed.test\msvc-11.0\debug\test_embed.pdb...
>
> ...removing bin\test_embed.test\msvc-11.0\debug\test_embed.pdb
>
> ...skipped test_embed.run for lack of test_embed.exe...
>
> ...failed updating 5 targets...
>
> ...skipped 4 targets...

Sorry to bother you with a large chunk of error message, I just want to provide as more information as I can.

About this `boost_python-vc110-gd-1_54.dll`, I can find it at `C:\local\boost_1_54_0_32bit\lib32-msvc-11.0`, while the root of my Boost is `C:\local\boost_1_54_0_32bit\`.

Can anyone help me work around with this?

Comment: This looks as though it is the same question as the one posted [hours earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19002587).  If they are the same, then please elaborate on the problem in a single question, rather than creating duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that the linker can't properly link to the Python lib. I have run into this before when trying to link to 64bit Python. You should try installing 32bit python and see if that works.

Comment: Hi, Kyle. Thanks for your advice. May I know how did you solve it? By installing a 32bit Python? I'm afraid that I cannot change Python version due to system limitation.

Comment: Correct, I solved it just by installing 32bit Python. I'm not sure what the details are around linking 64bit Python, but perhaps that can get you looking in the right spot.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Inspired by you, I'm trying to build Boost.Python in different ways. Would you mind tell me what was your system? Many thanks. :)

Comment: Sure, I had a very similar setup. Win 7 64bit, 32bit Python, VS 2012, Boost 1.54.

Answer (score 2):

Like Kyle C mentioned, this is happening because it can't find the lib. If you want to use 64-bit, you need to specify `address-model=64` on the command line, plus have the 64-bit version of python correctly specified in your user-config.jam file.

I [documented what I had to do to get this running](https://gist.github.com/teeks99/bb4921dffc8a74423c26#file-boost-python-quickstart-md), see the bottom for 64-bit specific config.