# Unable to install the boost library with 64bit version of Anaconda installed

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-2008, boost-python, anaconda

I am trying to install the boost library as shown here (see section install Boost from Shayne Fletcher:

http://www.amazon.com/review/R2QLTSQPKTFW5Z/ref=cm_cr_pr_cmt?ie=UTF8&ASIN=0470987847#wasThisHelpful

However I already have installed the 64 bit version of Anaconda for Python 2.7.5. So when I follow the instructions above I get the similar linking errors to the OP experienced in the post below:

[Cannot successfully install Boost.Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19008636/cannot-succesfully-install-boost-python)

The OP resolved the issue be removing the 64 bit version and replacing it with the 32 bit version.

However I wondered if I could install both versions and switch between them, it seems that generally speaking you can:

[Anaconda Python 32-bit is trying to load Anaconda 64-bit libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25246386/anaconda-python-32-bit-is-trying-)
to-load-anaconda-64-bit-libraries

However that sill leaves the question of how the boost library will know how to use the correct version and where to find it?

Or in my case would I still be better off removing the 64 bit version completely and installing the 32 bit version in its place?

I am doing the build in visual studio 2008.

Answer (score 3):

If you install the 32-bit version of Anaconda, you can `conda install boost`.

As for how to switch between them, you will need to modify your `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using 64-bit version.
Open Anaconda prompt in Admin mode and run the following command

> conda install -c anaconda boost

It will automatically resolve environment